# Как преобразовать данную структуру к switch case

Tags: java

```
public static void printObjectType(Object o) { 
//Напишите тут ваше решение 
if (o instanceof A) { 
//action1 
} 
if (o instanceof B) { 
//action 
} 
}
public static class A {}
public static class B {}
```

Comment: Здесь нету ошибки, мне просто не хочется прибегать к if. Вместо того чтобы городить 5 if для, скажем 5 разных классов, можно было бы переписать через switch case.

Comment: pavlofff, хотел бы закрыть вопрос, но не могу. Можете перенести ваш комментарий в ответ, чтобы я закрыл вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение в switch должно иметь тип char, byte, short, int, enum (начиная с Java 6) или String (начиная с Java 7). Использование любого другого типа приведет к ошибке компиляции.